# I am having a Problem with my C# Game (JSON / Update / Create )

Tags: c#, json, windows

I am currently working on my C# game. I asked many people in my local Discord's for help, but i never get an good or helpful answer. I am currently working on the player of my game.
The problem is that i need a good way to Save & Load with JSON Serialization.

My code on the end of this question doesn't work and i am low on ideas. I did rewrite the code for this question. This is an example.

I just need to Update some values to my Player.

```cs
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    random_number1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    random_number2 = rnd.Next(0, 5);

    string path = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "/saves/" + player + ".save";

    PlayerProfile player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerProfile>(File.ReadAllText(pfad));

    player.PlayerAttribute1 += random_number1;
    player.PlayerAttribute2 += random_number2;

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You get {0} Random_1 and {1} Random_2", random_number1, random_number2), "Alert");

    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player);

    UpdateUI();
}
```

If you need any other Information like my PlayerProfile class or other snippets of my script please write it in the answer or pn.

Comment: You should give more information about what is wrong, from this we can't tell if it can't find the file, or is setting fire to your PC...

Comment: Can you describe `doesnt work`?

Comment: What excatly does not work, and could you provide your code for PlayerProfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably write again to your file:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        random_number1 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        random_number2 = rnd.Next(0, 5);

        string path = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "/saves/" + player + ".save";

        PlayerProfile player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerProfile>(File.ReadAllText(pfad));

        player.PlayerAttribute1 += random_number1;
        player.PlayerAttribute2 += random_number2;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You get {0} Random_1 and {1} Random_2", random_number1, random_number2), "Alert");

        
        // Write again in your file system
        File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player));
        UpdateUI();

    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0